# Unable to map the array and get the values on Screen React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, react-native

```
const DynPut: FC<Props> = Props => {

const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(['1', '2', '3', '4']);

  return (
    <View>
      {value.map(v => {
        <Text>{v}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Unable to get the values 1-5 on the screen. am using typescript and also saved the file with `.tsx` extension

Comment: `;` is automatically added at the end inside the map function when saving the file. unable to get rid of it

Comment: Are you rendering the component somewhere, like app.tsx?

Comment: yes rendering the component in app.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the map is wrong, use normal brackets instead:

```
{value.map((v) => (
    <Text>{v}</Text>
))}
```

Comment: it solved the error. but in some cases we use `{` `}` also. correct me if am wrong, if we want to write more than one function or operation inside a map then we have to use `{` `}`

Comment: @AthavanT you can keep this as the accepted answer, I was just pointing out there are different methods.

Answer (score 2):

#### FYI

`map()` expects a return value, there are multiple possibilities, for example:

```js
const data = [{ x: 55, y: 34 }, { x: 75, y: 12 }];

const result1 = data.map(d => d.x); // inline

const result2 = data.map(d => (
  d.x // use round brackets
));

const result3 = data.map(d => {
  return d.x; // use return statement
});

console.log(result1, result2, result3);
```

The last method is handy if you want to do something with the data before returning a value.

```js
const data = [{ x: 55, y: 34 }, { x: 75, y: 12 }];

const result = data.map(d => {
  const xTimesFive = d.x * 5; // do something with the x value
  const dividedByTwo = xTimesFive / 2;
  return dividedByTwo;
});

console.log(result);

// note, a simple calculation or check can also be done in the other methods
console.log(data.map(d => d.x > 60 ? "big" : "small"));
```

Comment: Awesome, concise yet thorough answer. TIL, so thanks for that!

Comment: @jakehurt much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

To render the component inside map you need to add return or just brackets

```
{value.map((v) => (
    <Text>{v}</Text>
))}
```

Or

```
{value.map((v) => {
// enter code here (process)
return(
        <Text>{v}</Text>
    )
})}
```